# How can I make a load inductor for a double pulse test?

Tags: power-electronics, inductor, semiconductors, testing, powermosfet

How can I make a load inductor in the lab with value of roughly 115 uH for the sake of a double pulse test measurement? Do I need an LC meter to do that?

Comment: There are more manual ways to measure inductance without an LCR meter, but why is this an option to you? Unless you can buy it ready-made, you would like to verify the inductance?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need LCR meter, you need have a setup for gate driver and oscilloscope.

Comment: Yes i already have aribitary pulse generator and ossiloscope but how I am going to measure the load inductance value lets say if I make a load inductor myself using a stator winding.